# Need help checking proof of generalized replacement theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So the generalized replacement theorem goes as follows: Let $B$ be a basis for a vector space $V$, and let $S$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$. There exists a subset $S_1$ of $B$ such that $S\cup S_1$ is a basis for $V$.

My proof: Take $B$ and remove all vectors that are linear combinations of elements in $S$. This is the subset $S_1$ of $B$. $S \cup S_1$ is clearly spans $V$, since $S \cup S_1$ spans $B$ and $B$ spans $V$, and $S \cup S_1$ is also clearly independent. Therefore $S \cup S_1$ is a basis for $V$.

Am I missing anything here? this proof seems way too easy, I assumed that I needed the maximal principle in order to deal with infinite bases. Please do not link to any posts about the official proof, since I am still trying to work on this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that $S\cup S_1$ spans $V$, but not correct about independence, even in the finite-dimensional case.  Take for example $V={\Bbb R}^3$ and
$$B=\{(0,0,1),\,(0,1,1),\,(1,0,1)\}\ ,\quad S=\{(1,0,0),\,(0,1,0)\}\ .$$
Using your construction gives $S_1=B$, and $S\cup S_1$ is clearly not a basis for ${\Bbb R}^3$.

The point is that elements of $S_1$ are not linear combinations of $S$, but elements of $S$ may be linear combinations of $S_1$.

Comment: ah, I am clueless then. Any suggestions as to how i might get started on the proof? am i even on the right track? Because I know the proof by induction, but it does not apply for infinite bases.

Comment: Don't say "clueless": good idea but it didn't quite work - that happens sometimes.  No real idea on how to do the proof - Zorn's Lemma maybe????

Answer (score 0):

I think i just got an idea from your work before.

[1.] Remove any element in $\beta$ that are linear combination of elements in $S$. Name it $A_1$. Then $S\cup A_1$ generates $V$.

[2.] We have $S$ is linear independent set, $S\subset S\cup A_1$ and $S\cup A_1$ generates $V$.
Let

$B=\{ C\subset S\cup A_1 \text{ : }  C \text{ linearly independent set and } S\subseteqq C\}$.

This $B$ is non empty since $S\in B$. Using zorn lemma  (or maximal principal in linear algebra book by stephen friedberg) to get the maximal element (the proof is similar with the proof of theorem 1.13 in linear algebra by stephen friedberg). Name it $\gamma$.

[3. ]Then, we proof that $\gamma$ is a basis for $V$. (The proof can be seen in theorem 1.12 at linear algebra book by stephen friedberg).

[4.]  Note that $S\subset\gamma$ and ${\gamma\setminus S}\subset A_1\subset \beta$. Set $S_1=\gamma\setminus S$. We get what we want.

Please correct me if i did something wrong. Thanks